# Why does my front page only work in one language?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have problem with language of Drupal. When I click in home page in English language, the front page contains all content, nodes and blocks. When I click on other language, the front page doesn't show any contents and shows this message:

> No front page content has been created yet

How can I make 1 front page that contains the same blocks and content and is also translated in different languages?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I use it for a website with one single language in the front end (Spanish), and backend in english.

[image]

And..
[image]

All nodes are created using default language.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a node with some static content to display as homepage, and then set this node as your default front page for default language in

> admin/config/system/variable/edit/site_frontpage.

and then translate this node for other languages.

In order to display some views blocks especifically in your frontpage and in all languages, first make sure your block settings are

> Show block on specific pages : Only the listed pages : `<front>`

Then in view advanced settings, set *Field Language* as *Current user's language*

To complete, you can use [Internationalization views](https://drupal.org/project/i18nviews) to translate not dynamic content in your view, like views header, labels...